# Unable to extract to specific directory

Tags: shell, tar

I am trying to extract to file to specific directory but it doesn't produce result

Operating system : SunOS

Command:

```
zcat /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/3.tar.Z | tar -xf - -C /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/
```

if we remove value -C onwards in above command it produces result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

why not

```
cd /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/
tar xvzf /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/3.tar.Z
```

where

- you `cd` to /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/
- untar compressed file with `tar xvzf`

please note that untar will make recursive directory, for instance a tar of

```
 /foo/src/foo.c
 /foo/lib/bar.a
 /bar/whateever/etc/...
```

will make from starting directory, both `foo` abd `bar` dir, along with all subdir and files.